# How to change the pivot point of scaling to the center of selected vertices in Blender 2.8?

Tags: edit-mode, scale

[image: Image of a sphere in edit mode with vertices selected on top of the sphere]

I want to scale based on the center of the selected vertices in the image above. However, I don't know how to change the pivot point to the center of those vertices. I also don't think moving the object to the center of the global axis is the right way.

I think there was a function for this in previous versions, but I wonder if it disappeared? How does it work in Blender 2.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have bad transform pivot set up, you have to change it to the median point
[image]